# Realm - Reset Password

Tags: ios, realm

The steps mentioned at [Reset User Password](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/#resetting-a-useraposs-password) seems a bit confusing to me.
For example, A user normally reset his password because he cannot remember existing one.

Now, the above link mentions that

```
The refresh token can be retrieved by calling user.token after logging in via Realm.Sync.User
```

But, as user does not know his current password, how can the app get the refresh token?

I seem to be missing something here, not sure what..

Would be nice if someone could explain the complete steps for password reset by user.

Answer (score 0):

"Password reset" is a bit of a misnomer. The functionality in question is intended for a logged-in user to change their own password (for example, from a "Settings" or "Profile" screen), or for a user with administrative privileges to change an arbitrary user's password.

There is another common use case in which a user who is logged out and does not remember their password wishes to reset it. In many cases this process involves sending them an email with a link which, upon being visited, will allow them to specify a new password. The Realm Object Server doesn't support this sort of password reset out of the box; you may want to file an issue at its [issue tracker](https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues) to request it (since it seems quite important).